# Normal distribution is unique sum-stable distribution with finite variance (without using CLT)

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Is there a reasonably simple proof that the normal distribution is the unique [sum-stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) with finite variance? That is, for the claim

**Claim:** If $X_i$ are i.i.d. with mean zero and finite variance and $X_1 + X_2 \overset{\text{law}}{=} \sqrt{2}X_3$ then $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$.

A natural place to look for it would be in a book on sum-stable distributions, for instance "Chance and Stability" by Zolotarev et al. But it just mentions that this follows from the central limit theorem.

One can prove this after proving the central limit theorem, but I'd rather motivate the central limit theorem using this simpler fact.

My *secret motivation* is that I find proofs of the central limit theorem unsatisfying. (Even after scouring Stack Exchange and seeing proofs in terms of eigenfunctions of operators, strictly increasing entropy, dynamical systems, etc.) I just think there should be a more intuitive way.

Comment: Are you happy to look for characteristic functions satisfying $\varphi(t)^2 = \varphi(\sqrt{2}t)$ ?

Comment: I was going to say what Henry said. Does the book really say "CLT", not "characteristic function"?

Comment: "My secret motivation is that I find proofs of the central limit theorem unsatisfying. ": Then never mind what we said...

Comment: @Henry Sure, do you have a proof that that uniquely determines phi?

Comment: There are certainly many other functions which satisfy that functional equation, but they may not have other properties you desire: the simplest solution $\varphi(t)=0$ is obviously not a characteristic function.